# How to speed up access to JSON stored in HTML5 localStorage?

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, html, cordova

In my Cordova/PhoneGap app, I have a bunch of JSON code which is stored in localStorage and is used to render customized form fields. When as user clicks on an object, I retrieve the JSON from localStorage, parse it, iterate through all the objects to see if its ID matches the one I selected, when it finds a match, it runs a function to display the form fields. Like this:

```
    $(document).on('click', '.checklistObject', function() {
    var allChecklists = JSON.parse(localStorage.checklists);
    var element_id = $(this).attr("id");
    $.each(allChecklists, function(key, val) {
        if (val.id == element_id) {
            displayChecklist(val);
        }
    });
});
```

Right now this is really slow on older devices. Like 5 sec load times.

Is there a faster way to do this, preferably skipping the iteration part and just go straight to finding the object in localStorage, or storing the data in the `<li>` DOM object somehow and just grab it from there?

```
$('.checklistObject').click(function(){
    displayChecklist(this.jsonData);
 });
```

Comment: HTML3? Did you go back in time?

Comment: how big is the data array? If it's not very big any performance improvements may not be noticeable

Comment: @charlietfl I guess up to a 100k.

Comment: if it was object with keys matching the element ID's you wouldn't need to iterate. Also pulling out of storage before the click might help - such as right after page loads.

Comment: @charlietfl good idea. what does "pulling out of storage before the click" mean though?

Comment: meaning parse the json string to a javascript object before you actually need the object. Big string like that likely takes a bit of time to parse